# Wordpress app page not found error for posts with hyphen in permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I need some help related to permalinks.

I have two custom post types "books" and "authors"(created using CPT UI plugin).

i have created few authors where the permalink is generated as `http://wordpressproject.localhost/author/sagar-kumar-boina`,(with hyphens). This pages are giving page not found error.

But the books with hyphen in permalinks are working fine. (`http://wordpressproject.localhost/book/be-with-me`)

I'm trying since 2 days. can you plase help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

the first step would be to flush your permalinks by simply going to settings > permalinks and re-saving them, you don't actually need to change any settings.  If this does not fix the problem let us know.

Also I noticed that you say that you've created an 'authors' CPT though the URL you provided uses 'author' ( singular ) - is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

`author` is a reserved term and core query var WordPress uses for its user system, you are creating a conflict by registering a post type with the same slug.